# how to send data to controller with :remote => true with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to send data to controller in Rails3 with :remote => true(Unobtrusive JavaScript), but without link_to or form_tag. I want to send data(something param) to controller with jQuery response.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send data with ajax request using jQuery as below.

1. bind event depending upon class and
2. submit ajax request from jquery function

Code:

```
$(document).on('click',".ajaxRequestEvent",function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST'
url: url,
data: {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
});
```

where, 'ajaxRequestEvent' is the class of the element, on clicking which your request need to be sent. As above, you can send data with jquery ajax function's 'data' attribute